# animation on scroll the page in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the below snippet, I want to scroll down the page when it reaches the steps animation progress should start from 0 instead of middle. and when all three steps are done. it should show the below sections as well, as they are hidden. I am trying to add `position:fixed` when the step section reaches the header section on scroll. then when the yellow line reaches step 3 it should show the below 3 sections as well.

```js
const progressBar = document.querySelector('#yline');

const section = document.querySelector('section');

const scrollProgressBar = () => {

  progressBar.setAttribute('stroke-width', '0');
  var two = document.getElementById("timeline");

  var movEl = two.offsetTop;

  var res = movEl - document.documentElement.scrollTop - 5;

  if (res <= 10) {
    two.setAttribute('style', 'position: fixed; top:' + 5 + 'px;');
  } else {
    two.removeAttribute('style');
  }

  let scrollDistance = -(section.getBoundingClientRect().top);
  let scrollDistancetimeline = -(two.getBoundingClientRect().height);

  let progressPercentage =
    (scrollDistance /
      (section.getBoundingClientRect().height -
        document.documentElement.clientHeight)) * 100;


  let val = Math.floor(progressPercentage);

  if (val > 99) {
    two.style.position = 'relative';
    two.style.top = null;
  }
  progressBar.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', val + ' 100');

  progressBar.style.width = val + '%';

  if (val > 1) {
    progressBar.setAttribute('stroke-width', '4');
    progressBar.setAttribute('stroke', '#FCD535');

  }
};

window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollProgressBar);
```

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: #212121;
  --background-color: #111;
  --font: sans-serif;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: var(--background-color);
  font-family: var(--font);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.timeline {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  background: var(--primary-color);
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.newsection {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.mainline {
  width: 651px;
  height: 540px;
}

.roadline {
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
}

.yline {
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
  top: -25px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 640px;
  height: 590px;
}

.outer {
  position: relative;
}

.steps span {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.steps .step1 {
  left: -6px;
}

.steps .step2 {
  right: -9px;
  top: 251px;
}

.steps .step3 {
  bottom: 17px;
  left: -8px;
}

.boxes .box {
  height: 150px;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

.boxes .box1 {
  left: 20px;
  top: 10px;
}

.boxes .box2 {
  left: 20px;
  top: 194px;
}

.boxes .box .content {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.boxes .box .content .headings {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

.boxes .box .content .headings span {
  color: #fff;
}

.boxes .box .content .headings p {
  color: #7e7b7b;
}

.boxes .box2 .content .headings {
  text-align: right;
}

.boxes .box3 {
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 17px;
}

.roadline {
  height: 540px;
  width: 640px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .boxes .box {
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .timeline {
    width: 330px;
  }
  .boxes .box .content .headings p {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .mainline {
    width: 336px;
    height: 343px;
  }
  .content img {
    height: 76px;
  }
  .boxes .box2 {
    left: 21px;
    top: 111px;
  }
  .steps .step2 {
    right: -18px;
    top: 155px;
  }
  .steps .step1 {
    left: -10px;
    top: 13px;
  }
  .steps .step3 {
    bottom: 21px;
    left: -9px;
  }
  .boxes .box3 {
    bottom: -21px;
    left: 23px;
  }
  .yline {
    width: 327px;
    height: 310px;
    left: 5px;
    top: 15px;
  }
  .roadline {
    position: absolute;
    left: 3px;
    top: 11px;
  }
  .roadline {
    height: 320px;
    width: 329px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>

  <div class="newsection green">

  </div>

  <div class="newsection yellow">

  </div>

  <div class="timeline" id="timeline">
    <div class="outer">
      <div>
        <div class="steps">
          <span class="step1">1</span>
          <span class="step2">2</span>
          <span class="step3">3</span>
        </div>

        <div class="boxes">
          <div class="box box1">
            <div class="content">
              <div class="headings">
                <span>Shop</span>
                <p>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/hsGs36R.jpg">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="box box2">
            <div class="content">
              <div>
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/hsGs36R.jpg">
              </div>
              <div class="headings">
                <span>Play</span>
                <p>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..</p>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="box box3">
            <div class="content">
              <div class="headings">
                <span>Win</span>
                <p>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/hsGs36R.jpg">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>


        <svg class='mainline' viewBox="0 0 851 669" fill="none" xmlns="    http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M8.54688 8V164C8.54688 186.091 26.4555 204 48.5469 204H802.547C824.638 204 842.547 221.909 842.547 244V419C842.547 441.091 824.638 459 802.547 459H48.5469C26.4555 459 8.54688 476.909 8.54688 499V661" stroke="#181A20" stroke-width="16" stroke-linecap="round"/>
                  </svg>

        <svg class="roadline" viewBox="0 0 836 655" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/ svg">
                  <path d="M0.546875 1V157C0.546875 179.091 18.4555 197 40.5469 197H794.547C816.638 197 834.547 214.909 834.547 237V412C834.547 434.091 816.638 452 794.547 452H40.5469C18.4555 452 0.546875 469.909 0.546875 492V654" stroke="#484E5F" fill-opacity="0.1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="10 10"/>
              </svg>

        <svg class="yline" viewBox="0 0 837 655" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path 
                   id='yline'
                   d="M1.54688 1V157C1.54688 179.091 19.4555 197 41.5469 197H795.547C817.638 197 835.547 214.909 835.547 237V412C835.547 434.091 817.638 452 795.547 452H41.5469C19.4555 452 1.54688 469.909 1.54688 492V654"
                   stroke-width="4" 
                   stroke-linecap="round"
                   pathlength="100.1"
                   stroke-dashoffset="0"
                   stroke-dasharray="10 100"
                   />
                </svg>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="newsection red">

  </div>

  <div class="newsection yellow">

  </div>

  <div class="newsection green">

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I cannot see the `#yline` element from your snippets.

What's the problem you are getting?

Comment: when all three steps are completed. it should move to the bottom section.

Comment: What do you mean by "when all three steps are completed"? 
There is no animation currently firing when you scroll. I get an error in the console because in the js you are trying to set an attribute to the `progressBar` element, but that is `null`.